# Remotely connect to Exchange 2019

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-2019

I'm currently trying to write a skript that'll automatically connect to one of our exchange servers to open a exchange management shell remotely. This is the script I have written so far:

```
$servers = "ex1.domain.local", "ex2.domain.local"
$server = $servers[(Get-Random -Maximum $servers.count)]
$credential = Get-Credential domain\administrator  -Message "Enter your login credentials"
write-host "Connecting remote PowerShell to $($server)..."
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://$server/PowerShell/ -Credential $credential
New-PSSession -Session $session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber
```

The script seems to run just fine but unfortunately the powershell console window immediately closes after `New-PSSession -Session $session -DisableNameChecking -AllowClobber`.
Whenever I paste these command into a powershell script seperately it works just fine.

How can I alter this script to not automatically close the console window after importing a powershelkl session?

Comment: What happens when you use `Import-PSSession $session` ?

Comment: @Smeerpijp The same thing happens: No error, but the script closes immediately

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the script with the `-noexit` switch. I personally use an `.bat` file to call a powershell.exe process with the switch.

Example:

`powershell -noexit "C:\Scripts\PSSession_Exchange\ExchangePowerShell.ps1"`

Run the `.bat`  file, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

About the code issue, I suggest you post it on the [Microsoft TechNet Exchange Sever Development forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/home?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment).

Answer (score 0):

I use `Read-Host "Press Enter"` which will wait for the user input of the Enter key to finish running.